# Flex how to use callLater?

Tags: apache-flex

In my flex mobile application, I have a loop running for over 100 iterations. In each iteration I'm updating some properties of specific Label(s). Since the loop is time consuming, I need to update the screen and display intermediate results at each iteration. How can I break the loop and refresh the display list?

```
function theFunction():void{
 for var i:int = 0; i < n; i++{
  doBusyStuff();
  label_1.text = "iteration"+" i";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that situation, I prefer to use `flash.utils.setTimeout()`

```
import flash.utils.setTimeout;

function theFunction(limit:int, current:int = 0):void 
{
    if (current >= limit)
        return;

    doBusyStuff();
    label_1.text = "iteration "+ current.toString();

    setTimeout(theFunction, 0, limit, current+1);
}
```

However, both `setTimeout()` and `callLater()` depend on the tick or the frame rate, meaning that they won't do as fast as they can. So if you also want it to run faster, you should have it run a few loops per each call.

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods to force redraw of components:

```
invalidateDisplayList();
invalidateProperties();
invalidateSize();
```

Just use whatever you need for your components inside a function and call it after your script using `callLater(yourRedrawFunction);`

EDIT: For example, in your case:

```
function theFunction():void{
 for var i:int = 0; i < n; i++{
  doBusyStuff();
  label_1.text = "iteration"+" i";
 }
 callLater(yourRedrawFunction);
}
```

Comment: where do i have to call the "callLater"? in another function? i would appreciate if you can use my example above. regards

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, similar to Chaniks' answer, uses `DateTime` to check how long the loop has been running on each iteration.  Once it detects that it's been running for too long, it ends the loop and picks up again on the next Frame.

```
var i:int;
function callingFunction():void {
  i = 0;
  stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, theFunction);
}

function theFunction(e:Event):void {
  var time:DateTime = new DateTime();
  var allowableTime:int = 30;  //Allow 30ms per frame
  while ((new DateTime().time - time.time < allowableTime) && i < n) {
    doBusyStuff();
    i++;
  }
  if (i >= n) {
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, theFunction);
  }
  label_1.text = "iteration"+" i";
}
```